# How to create a paid Android app with trial mode?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am developing an Android app with two modes

1. Trial - free with limited functionality. The user has no time limit here. They can continue to use the app for forever but will not have access to full functionality.
2. Paid - full functionality. The user can make a one time payment to gain full functionality.

I have seen some posts indicating that you could publish two different apps to the Play store, but I would prefer to publish one app and use an internal flag to limit functionality when in Trial mode.

What is the best way to do this on Play Console? Should I set the App pricing as free and then add an In-app product for the paid version? Then from my app I can have a button that makes the request for the purchase?

The Play store indicates that once an app is published as free then it cannot be changed to paid? Is there some way to indicate paid app that has trial with limited functionality?

I don't want to use Subscription since the payment is one-time to get the full App.

Are there other good options to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing) is the Google recommended way to do this (integrates with GPay nicely), otherwise you can use other payment processors and setup a server configuration to verify users purchases.

Using only an internal flag is not recommended as if users ever clear app data/uninstall their purchase is lost.

Comment: As an aside, the typical production application distinguishes between free/paid in the title (i.e. "Android Application - Pro"). Also if you use the billing library to create in-app purchases the Play Store will put a notation on your listing that denotes that your app contains in app purchases.

Comment: I plan to use the Google Play Billing library but how to register the app in play store? The ideal solution would be to register as a paid app but seems like there is no option for trial there and I need to charge upfront. If I go with subscription then there is trial option but subscription has reoccurring charges. Going as free with in app purchase has the problem you mentioned and it gives the user the wrong impression as the free version is very limited.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) for instructions on integrating into your application for in app billing (note that it does not seem to be labeled as such anymore in the docs). **You can list your app as free and still utilize the in app billing.**